Tilt curve to face object
Update: please check the end of the post I may have found a solution.
I'm making a node tree whose purpose is to tilt the points of a curve so they face a reference object. A Plane is generated from the curve and so it also faces the reference object. I think I am almost there except for a problem of angle calculation.
Here is the test file: 
In the following example, I am attaching a 3D gizmo to the faces of the reference objet (a sphere) as well as the curve points. The idea is to calculate the angle difference on a specific axis between the reference object closest face's normal and a vector of the curve point (here tangent) then set the tilt to that angle. This seems to be working except sometimes some rotations change range such as moving from -64° to 114° when moving the last curve point (the one selected on the example file when opening it).I guess I have to clamp the angles in some way but I am not sure how to prevent them from skipping like this and what the right range should be.
Here is a screen of the last curve point having wrong tilt as well as the node tree applied on the curve:


UPDATE: I have a potential solution for this using quaternions: instead of using Rotation To Euler before subtracting the two angles, I used Rotation To Quaternion. Then I got the W of each quaternion using cos(Z/2) and made the subtract on these. So far it looks good, I'll update the post if I find any issue.

related: Trimming start of the curve geometry nodes without altering tilt - sample nearest surface normal, and use the angular difference between it and current normal as the curve tilt.

Just want to be sure this doesn't take you most of the way in Blender 4.1.1 :  https://imgur.com/a/Ej9y3h6

@RobinBetts ohhh it's a new feature! I thought I was reading the 4.1 changelog but missed it somehow...

@RobinBetts thank you! This is much simpler than what I was doing and seems to be working fine. You can set it as answer if you wish!

Hi, @Alio! Great! could we leave that to you, to self-answer? I have to be unexpectedly AFK for a while.

Ok, will do it after I have tested the solution in several contexts.

@Robin Betts made a comment above which answers the question, providing a much simpler solution than the one I was implementing. Check it at https://imgur.com/a/Ej9y3h6, I am pasting the images below as well.


